# Please reopen One-word synonym - follow up?

Tags: discussion

Please reopen https://ell.stackexchange.com/q/31078/8712? I apologise for https://ell.stackexchange.com/q/38702/8712; I can't view deleted questions.

Comment: Why? It wasn't a question fit for the site, you didn't accept the one answer that was posited; I don't see any reason to reopen the question.

Comment: @jimsug Why wasn't it 'fit'? I'd like to accept the answer, but can't?

Comment: [You had twelve days](http://i.imgur.com/trNBxr4.png) to accept the answer **and** edit the question. It was closed because we aren't a thesaurus, we are a resource for language learners. Setting arbitrary limits on possible answers is not constructive - English doesn't work in a way that all phrasal verbs have single-word synonyms (the very concept of _synonym_ is contentious).

Comment: @jimsug I'd appreciate the opportunity to edit it now, to seek synonyms not just (single-word synonyms)?

Comment: I have voted to undelete it, however I believe it will remain closed until/unless you improve it and it is voted upon again.

Answer (score 2):

**Which part of snailplane's comment do you not understand?**

> Single word requests are off-topic on ELL. We should focus on how to express something naturally, not how to express something within arbitrary game-like limits like "a single orthographic word".

That summarizes my thoughts on the question.

---

**As for this comment you just made:**

> I'd appreciate the opportunity to edit it now, to seek synonyms (not just single-word synonyms)?

I'm having trouble understanding why you'd solicit those synonyms on ELL, and not merely [consult a thesaurus](http://www.thesaurus.com/browse/follow%20up?s=t).

Comment: I'm voting in good faith, that the user will provide words suggested by a thesaurus that don't quite elicit the meaning they intend. But of course, that's contingent on four (?) other people voting to undelete.

Comment: @jimsug - I'm wondering why, even when the O.P. tried to re-ask the question, not a peep was mentioned about **why** _follow up_ wouldn't suffice. I mean, what on earth is wrong with, "I'll follow up with another email." Even if this were reopened, this just seems destined to be another one of [a long list of mediocre questions](http://ell.stackexchange.com/users/8712/upvote-law-area-51-proposal?tab=questions&sort=votes&page=5).

Comment: @J.R.: Please advise if your second blockquote of me answers your first question. Your 2nd question: I did, and wrote about this. I'm still asking because the thesaurus entries are noncontextual?

Comment: @UpvoteLawArea51Proposal JR has raised convincing concerns about your new question. I can't retract my close vote. But you really should have made a better case in the re-post of your question.

Comment: First, there was "please reopen the question." Then, there was "I want to accept the answer, but I can't." After that, we had "to seek synonyms not just (single-word synonyms)." It seems like you're grasping at straws. Moreover, your plea here has already garnered 4 downvotes in a mere matter of hours. I don't think you have much of a case here, and see no reason to reopen. I'd advise you to drop the matter.

Comment: @jimsug Community deletion and undeletion each require 3 votes rather than 5, I believe.